# Хватит [проверок]!

Tags: предложение, удаление-метки

На ruSO есть метка [проверка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0) (27 вопросов).

ИМХО она не несет никакой смысловой нагрузки и должна быть удалена (и заблокирована).

Если здесь есть специалисты по проверкам - аргументируйте её сохранение! ;-)

Comment: Ее надо либо удалять вместе с метками [tag:if], [tag:else] и [tag:условия] - либо делать их все синонимами.

Comment: Согласен, но если задача не решается целиком, то можно начать по частям

Comment: Решением по частям будет синонимизация.

Comment: Решением по частям будет удаление. Синонимизировать - это отдельный вопрос/процесс.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а почему синоним должен быть условия, а не тестирование?

Comment: @Grundy тестирование это вроде вообще из другой оперы (TDD, юнит-тесты и иже с ними)

Comment: @Kromster, тестирование - тестировать - проверять - проверка -> вроде логично

Comment: @Grundy так можно от чего угодно к чему угодно придти )))

Comment: @Grundy потому что метка именно так используется

Answer (score 2):

Я вижу, что эту метку можно без потери качества удалить для всех 26 вопросов. Эта метка похожа на мета-метку. Занесение в чёрный список требует от Николаса дёргать определённых сотрудников StackExchange, что в данном случае, как мне кажется,  того не стоит. Можно без проблем довольно быстро всё удалить вручную и только если эта метка начнёт часто появляться, то можно будет задать новый вопрос, но не уверен, что до этого дойдёт.

По поводу меток удаления меток [if](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if), [else](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/else) и [условия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f) не согласен, считаю что они имеют право на существование. По поводу синонимизации согласен. В любой случае по ним хорошо бы открыть отдельное обсуждение.